# Unexpected IndexOutOfBoundException when getting value of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(30);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
        values.add(i, 0);
    }
    int j = 0;
    int ghh = values.get(j);
}
```

Above is a simple code snippet that gives an `OutOfBoundException` at the last line. Why is this exception being thrown? Do I actually need to use the for-loop for initiating `0` value of all the elements of the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for loop does nothing, since `values.size()` is `0`. That's the reason why `values.get(j)` throws an exception (the list remains empty).

Change the loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    values.add(i, 0);
}
```

When you create an `ArrayList` instance with this constructor - `new ArrayList<>(30)` - you are specifying the initial capacity, not the initial size. The initial size is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you assume `new ArrayList<>(30)` creates a list with 30 slots already "allocated" (so that `.size()` would return `30`).

But that is not what actually happens. This constructor only specifies the initial *capacity* of the list. Meaning, you can now *add* 30 elements, and the underlying list will not need to dynamically grow. But you still have to *add* at least one element, before you can do a `get(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The Array list constructor 'ArrayList(int initialCapacity)' creates an empty list with a initial capacity received.

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(30);
```

`values` is an empty list at this point. You set an initial capacity but this doesn't create any element in the list.

```
for (int i = 0 ;i<values.size() ; i++){
```

`values.size()` is 0, so the line inside the loop is not being executed.

```
int ghh = values.get(j);
```

`values` is still an empty list, so values.get(0) throws an `IndexOutOfBoundException`

> Do I actually need to use the for-loop for initiating 0 value of all the elements of the list?

You need to manually add the elements to the list using the for loop.

As an alternative, in Java8, you could use an Stream to generate the list:

```
List<Integer> list = Stream.generate(()-> 0).limit(30).collect(Collectors.toList());
```